# How to iterate a dictionary through indirection

Tags: bash, associative-array

I want to implement in bash the following pseudocode

```
function gen_items() {
    dict=$1 # $1 is a name of a dictionary declared globally
    for key in $dict[@]
    do
         echo $key ${dict[$key]}
         # process the key and its value in the dictionary
    done
}
```

The best I have come by is

```
function gen_items() {
    dict=$1
    tmp="${dict}[@]"
    for key in "${!tmp}"
    do
        echo $key
    done
```

}

This actually only gets the values from the dictionary, but I need the keys as well.

Comment: Without namerefs, indirect variable construction is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Use a nameref:

```
show_dict() {
  ((BASH_VERSINFO[0] < 4 || ((BASH_VERSINFO[0] == 4 && BASH_VERSINFO[1] < 3)))) &&
    { printf '%s\n' "Need Bash version 4.3 or above" >&2; exit 1; }
  declare -n hash=$1
  for key in "${!hash[@]}"; do
    echo key=$key
  done
}

declare -A h
h=([one]=1 [two]=2 [three]=3)
show_dict h
```

Output:

```
key=two
key=three
key=one
```

---

See:

- [How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)
- [Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using GNU bash, version 4.1.2 and declare does not support -n option. Yes, on bash 4.4.x declare -n hash=$1 works fine.